# Unity UI Pop Up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, and many of these principals I am just blanking on.

I build a dialogue system and its working great, but I want to make a confirmation box.

I have managed to get the confirmation box to pull up, but I cant seem to figure out how to wait for one of the Yes / No buttons are pushed before the code is returned to the Dialogue manager with the proper bool.

Right now the code pushes on behind the dialogue box. Which is expected.

I tried an enumerator but I must have been doing it wrong because it did not matter.

I just cleaned up the code to try to start from scratch.

```
public bool AskForTakingMoney(){
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(true);
        goldText.text = "Current Gold: " + GameManager.instance.currentGold.ToString() + "G";
        questionText.text = "Pay the " + DialogManager.instance.goldAmount + "G?";
        //Wait here until yes or no button pushed
        return saysYes;
    }
    public void SaysYes(){
        saysYes = true;
        selectedAnswer = true;
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);
    }
     public void SaysNo(){
        saysYes = false;
        selectedAnswer = true;
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);

    }
```

I really just need the return function to not go back until the yes or no button is pushed.

I am at a complete loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a popup, then the popup should be responsible for what happens next.

So your `AskForTakingMoney` should never return a value. Instead you need to assign the `onclick` events for the Yes and No button.

Your code should simply be:

```
public void AskForTakingMoney(){
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(true);
        goldText.text = "Current Gold: " + GameManager.instance.currentGold.ToString() + "G";
        questionText.text = "Pay the " + DialogManager.instance.goldAmount + "G?";
    }

    public void SaysYes(){           
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);
        // Your withdraw money code here.
    }

     public void SaysNo(){
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Then from within the Editor, click on your Yes Button. 
You should see an onclick field like the one in the picture. Click on the plus sign, then drag in your MonoBehaviour object which is holding the code with  above functions. 
After dragging it in, You should be able to select `SaysYes` from the dropdown that appears under 'YourScriptName' -> 'SaysYes()'

Do the same for your No Button and you should be all set.

[image: OnClick]

Comment: This is how it is set up. What happens is my dialog manager calls the taking money script if the character requires money to complete the task. This is what calls the confirm pop up. So set up as you said. I need the script to return a true or false value (unless I am approaching this wrong) to let the dialog manager know to withdraw money or abandon the dialog.

Comment: You withdraw the money by adding in your `withdraw money code` into the `SaysYes()` method. 
Abandoning the dialog should be no more than setting the dialogbox to inactive in your `SaysNo()` method.

Comment: This makes sense, but the dialog manager still will need to know if you pushed yes or not before proceeding to the next line of code. Edit- I see what your saying. let me play with some code and see what I come up with.

Comment: I have some difficulty understanding your problem statement. Can't you simply call something like `DialogManager.Instance.YesPressed` from within the `SaysYes()` method?

Comment: Ok I think the way you are explaining the flow works, for the most part. What is happening is my DialogManager is controlling the flow of the dialog, When it comes to a string that I have predetermined when the character asks for money, the pop up window comes up in this script. Depending on if the character says Yes or No is going to determine if the dialogue will continue or not. But what I think I am going to try is your code and just have it move to the next line regardless, and pushing the no button will just shut down everything right from the no button.

Comment: Ok this logic is working with some tweaking I did. Thank you very much. I figured it was just the approach I was taking. This works well.

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

Make Two Buttons, Set them to active at the end of AskForTakingMoney(), Make those buttons lead to SaysYes(); and SaysNo();

Edit: Comment if you need clarification. I may not be understanding you clear enough. Do you even have buttons set up?

Comment: THis is how it is set up. The thing is that the dialog manager is what calls this popup, and it needs to know if you selected yes or no. Right now it calls the take money script and then just keeps going after the popup takes place and automatically returns a value for not taking money.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need the function to not care about returning what they clicked, and each frame check (in the update method, or in a coroutine) if the button has been pressed by checking your selectedAnswer variable.

Or you could run some code in a separate thread, and use WaitHandle's, to cause the thread to pause until the button has been pressed.

Example using your code:

```
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
    EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(false,EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    Thread _thread;
    public void StartThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(BackgroundThreadFunction);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void BackgroundThreadFunction()
    {
        if (AskForTakingMoney())
        {
            //Yes
        }
        else
        {
            //No
        }
    }

    public bool AskForTakingMoney()
    {
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(true);
        goldText.text = "Current Gold: " + GameManager.instance.currentGold.ToString() + "G";
        questionText.text = "Pay the " + DialogManager.instance.goldAmount + "G?";

        //Wait here until yes or no button pushed
        handle.WaitOne();

        return saysYes;
    }

    public void SaysYes()
    {
        saysYes = true;
        selectedAnswer = true;
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);

        handle.Set();
    }

    public void SaysNo()
    {
        saysYes = false;
        selectedAnswer = true;
        takingMoneyBox.SetActive(false);

        handle.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I am not sure when it would respond to the UI button push. The popup is controlled buy the first function and then the 2 functions below are tied to the yes or no buttons. The way its set up now, the response still goes through and pushes a false result.